# A case of mistaken identity, or, "You can't vote for your own post" on somebody else's post

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just attempted to up-vote someone else's post on a question and got this: [screenshot http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5852/sobugged.png](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5852/sobugged.png)

However, I'm not Matthew Flaschen!  In addition, my up-vote was reflected when I clicked it pictured), but when I refreshed the page the answer was back to zero (this could have been because someone down-voted it, I guess).

In case it's relevant, I'm currently running Safari 4.0.4.

Comment: Does it happen every time?

Comment: No, which is frustrating.  (I'm posting this hoping that someone else might have encountered the same problem and have a more precise repro.)  The problem I'm having *now* is that it complains "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited."  (For an answer that I have no outstanding vote on.)

Comment: This happens if you upvote it, cancel the vote and wait a while.

Comment: Confirmed with another answer.  But in this case it didn't *appear* to have successfully upvoted it (it gave me the 'you can't vote for your own post' message and didn't highlight either arrow).  I'll spend some more time trying to reproduce the original condition and see if this is a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this same issue. The sequence of events (maybe this helps reproduce):

1. First to answer a question
2. Started editing my answer - but needed to create a diagram, which required updating some software, which required closing browser (Safari)
3. Returned to page next day; edits were still there (that is awesome, by the way!)
4. Finished my edit and posted updated answer
5. Noticed someone else had posted a useful answer in the meantime
6. Decided to upvote the useful answer
7. Got the same message as seen by Arkaaito
8. Refreshed the page; was now able to vote

In case it helps, the question on which this happened was [2D Interpolation irregular grid fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478551/2d-interpolation-irregular-grid-fortran/17478880#17478880)

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this.

Comment: Jeff - I just ran into this issue and have posted the steps that led to it (not sure it can be reproduced since I can't answer "as two different people" to a question...)

Comment: @flo - FYI, Jeff [doesn't work at Stack Exchange anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/thank-you-jeff-atwood). You added an answer which bumped this post up - so I'm sure it'll get noticed again by the team (just like I noticed it!)

Comment: @Lix thanks for letting me know. I didn't realize that just adding the answer would "bump" this. Good to know.